# Display posts from catagories

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I am using an option framework. This saves catagory ids.To get ids I have done

```
$cat = $atts['post_catagory'];
var_dump($cat);
```

The var dump result is

`array (size=2)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '15' (length=2)`

Here 1 and 15 are catagory ids. To query posts I have used

```
$args = array( 'orderby'=> ASC,'cat'=>$cat);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '"   
title="'.the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
endforeach;
```

But I got error. Also can do the same query using wp_query?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat` needs to be an `int` or `string`, and you are passing an `array`. Either use [`category__in`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) instead, which accepts an array, or convert `$cat` to a string of values with `implode(',', $cat)`

Comment: Works like a charm